# Tiling geocoded aerials in QGIS 2

Tags: tiles, qgis-2, aerial-photography

I have two geocoded aerials from the Las Vegas valley from different years. The newer aerial has an area missing from the Northwest part of town. The older aerial has the missing area I need.

My question is, Is there a way to tile the new and old aerials and fill in the missing area from the older one and combine the two into one composite that I can export from QGIS? If not is there free software that would tile the two and output a composite geocoded aerial?

Answer (score 1):

You may use [gdal_merge.py](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_merge.html#description)

You should use

```bsh
gdal_merge.py -o composite_las_vegas.tif las_vegas_old.tif las_vegas_more_recent.tif
```

You may need to use options for managing "nodata"

Answer (score 0):

You can mosaic the two images and export them as a raster file, which is a georeferenced image combining the old and the new image.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B7rxR0tmz_0